# Animate.css not working in firefox

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/xmesop57/

1. The bounce in effect is jerky in firefox. When I keep refreshing the page, sometimes the effect applies and sometimes it doesn't. But either ways, the bounce in jerky. All fine in chrome though.
2. There is a huge color difference between chrome and firefox. Why is it. Can this be fixed. My expected color is as seen in firefox.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid radial-center">
        <div class="centering text-center col-lg-3 clearfix">
            <div class="animated bounceInLeft">
                <input type="text" class="textbox" id="txtUsername" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.radial-center {
    /* fallback */
    background-color: #413636;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#370237), to(#413636));
    /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #490338, #121211);
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #D52B48, #413636);
    /* IE 10 */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #D52B48, #413636);
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
.bounceInLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
}
```

Comment: try add this for background `background: #413636;`. also had you checked your browser cache? it can cause animation sometimes stuck...

Comment: @SoursopTree.Where exactly should I add that property.In `radial-center`? I did. nothings changed

Comment: @MrLister: Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. (Those should have been two different questions, really.)

1. A problem in Firefox is that there's a horizontal scrollbar at one point, which causes the vertical size of the window to change briefly.
   Solution: give `overflow-x:hidden` to `body`.
2. You don't have the same colours in the `-webkit-` and `-moz-` prefixed gradients.
   Solution: make sure the colours are the same, and/or add an unprefixed `radial-gradient` after the prefixed ones.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow-x:hidden; /* here */
}
.container-fluid {
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
}
.container-fluid:after {
    content:none;
}
.container-fluid:before {
    content:none;
}
.row-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.centering {
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
}
.col-lg-3 {
  text-align:center;
}
.radial-center {
    /* fallback */
    background-color: #413636;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#D52B48), to(#413636)); /* corrected colours */
    /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #D52B48, #413636); /* corrected colours */
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #D52B48, #413636);
    /* modern browsers */
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #D52B48, #413636); /* removed -ms- */
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounceInLeft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-2000px);
        transform: translateX(-2000px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-2000px);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(30px);
        transform: translateX(30px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(30px);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-10px);
        transform: translateX(-10px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
.bounceInLeft {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    animation-name: bounceInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name:bounceInLeft;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid radial-center">
        <div class="centering text-center col-lg-3 clearfix">
            <div class="animated bounceInLeft">
                <input type="text" class="textbox" id="txtUsername" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Or, [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xmesop57/3/)).

By the way, there is no `-ms-radial-gradient`.

Comment: Thank you Lister. That was stupid of me to not notice that. However, the animation is still jerky in firefox but not in chrome. Please run the fiddles and you can see....

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the jerkiness in Firefox. The only difference between Firefox and Chrome now is that when I click "Run code snippet", Chrome's output frame flashes to white briefly before redrawing the red background; Firefox doesn't. Other than that, no differences.